# What's an Account in the updated MS Azure organizational structure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Two years ago I had a training on MS Azure Fundamentals. Back in those days the Azure orgnizational structure was:

Account -> subscription (+Directory) -> resource group -> resource

Now I am about to refresh my knowledge and see that this was changed to

Management Group -> management group / Subscription (+ Directory) -> resource group -> resource

Was it just renamed or do I have a missleading picture of an "account" in my mind thinking that this is a encapsulating entity where I can do some major/general configuration.

What I find searching the web for information on that topic never gives an holistic overview on the interchange between all those elements:

- User Account
- Directory (same as AAD)
- Tenant
- Subscription
- Did I forget something on the first levels?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on the right track please check the below Architectural structure
[image]

[image]